# Algolia autocomplete js with select2

Tags: autocomplete, algolia

I am using aloglia autocomplete.js and followed the tutorial.
I want to use autocomplete text box with others select2 selectbox.

```
var client = algoliasearch('YourApplicationID','YourSearchOnlyAPIKey')
var index = client.initIndex('YourIndex');
autocomplete('#search-input', { hint: false }, [
{
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
  displayKey: 'my_attribute',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
      return suggestion._highlightResult.my_attribute.value;
    }
  }
}
]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
console.log(suggestion, dataset);
$("#search-input").val(suggestion.full_name.name)
});
```

Problem is when I clicked anywhere beside that autocomplete box autocomplete disappear and it showed only what I typed before.

I don't want it to disappear. How can I implement it? Thanks for helping.

Please see the example below for detail problem.

> Assume you have a simple form with one auto complete input field,two select2 boxes and one submit button. After you choose auto complete filed, when you click anywhere, it changed to default text. I mean, you put "piz" and it shows "pizza". Therefore you select pizza and it display "pizza".Then, you try to choose one select2 box or click anywhere. The autocomplete input field changed back to "piz".

I tried autocomplete:closed , $("#search-input").focusout to set the input field but it just changed back to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have it. When you need to only select and not to do any action, you can safety remove **autocomplete:selected**. And make sure your **display key** is value **not object**.

It saves me for trouble.

Comment: For displayKey, simple value is ok, but i want to put it like displayKey: 'title.title', is there any way to put like this?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it from disappearing, you can use `autocomplete.js`'s `debug` option:

```
autocomplete('#search-input', { hint: false, debug: true }, [ /* ... */ ]);
```

The [complete options list](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options) is available on GitHub.

Comment: Its for editing css or etc. Assume u have a simple form with one auto complete input field,two select2 boxes and one submit button. After you choose auto complete filed, when you click anywhere, it changed to default text. I mean, you put "piz" and it shows "pizza". Therefore you select pizza and it display "pizza".Then, you try to choose  one select2 box or click anywhere. The autocomplete input field changed back to "piz". Sorry for I didnt mention in my problem in details. I will edit. Thanks for suggestion. @Jerska

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification. A fiddle would definitely help debugging the issue.